# Does esbuild provide a feature similar like resolve.extensions and resolve.modules option in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, esbuild

I'm learning esbuild and trying to migrate my project from Webpack to esbuild. I'm wondering if esbuild provides a feature or if any other plugins work similarly like the `resolve.extensions` and `resolve.modules` options in Webpack?

Sort of replicate the same function in esbuild like this in webpack:

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you gone through [esbuild documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/)? You might want to consider using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) instead (it uses esbuild under the hood).

Comment: esbuild has a `loader` instance for resolving extensions. Refer to https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/ for usage.

Comment: @Valentin I'm having this question because of I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"` when I'm running the app on the browser(chrome). And it seems to be chrome didn't know where to find "react", so I'm suspecting this could be due to esbuild not resolving the "react" properly. I've tried using the "inject" instance to inject a "react-shim.js" which imports "react" and exports it, but no luck for me. As well as using the `loader` instance.

Comment: @first Yup, I've tried it `loader: {".js": ".jsx"}`, but it doesn't work as I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`. So probably esbuild is not resolving "react" properly.

Comment: @Leonkong I understand, I'm just telling you that Vite is probably an easier way that barebones esbuild and it uses esbuild under the hood.